# Lower-semicontinuous map defined on probability measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Denote by $P(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and let $f: \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a lower-semicontinuous function.

Define $K(\mu) = \int \int f(x-y) d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$ for $\mu \in P(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I am trying to show that $K$ is also lower-semicontinuous. ie for $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ weakly, it holds that $K(\mu) \leqslant \liminf \limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} K(\mu_n)$.

The hint that I have is that i must use the continuity of the map $\mu \rightarrow \mu \otimes \mu$, $f\geqslant 0$ and lower-semicontinuous and Fatou's lemma.
However, I cannot put everything together. Could you give me some help ? or show me how to start with the proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the argument you need on page 19 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6860.pdf

Comment: in page 19 it doesn't explain anywhere why the lsc V potential preserves the lsc of the functional I . Does it ? there is computation only for the continuous part ie. g function

Comment: Weak star convergence of measures always gives lower semicontinuity of integrals of bounded an lower semicontinous functions. Indeed these can always be approximated from below by bounded continuous functions...